# How to make a sticky navigation bar on the right side of the page?

Tags: html, css

[image]
I would like to build a site with a stick nav bar on the right side. I'm new to web development. How can I achieved this? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Generally to speak this is kind of a wierd idea to put a navbar to the right side. All the browsers put the scrolbar to te right side.

Anyways

you should apply css to the site.

```
.navbar{
    background-color:red;
    position:sticky;
    height:100vh;
    top:0;
    float:right;
}

.content{
    height:2000px;
    margin-top:10px;
    margin-right:120px;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

And in the html

```
<div class="navbar">
   This is the navbar
</div>
<div class="content">
  Content
</div>
```

Comment: How do I make it sticky so only the content part scrolls?

Comment: Updated my code. You have to use position sticky for .navbar